# SQlite concat select statement

Tags: sqlite, select

I would like to know if it is possible to concat and add a space in SQlite. This is what I mean:

```
SELECT NAME || SURNAME AS USER_NAME FROM USERS
```

But then add something to the query to let the result be displayed as:

```
Name Surname
```

and not

```
NameSurname
```

Is something like this possible in SQlite?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Concat also the space:

```
SELECT NAME || ' ' || SURNAME AS USER_NAME FROM USERS
```

Answer (score 6):

A hack in PHP when using Laravel. It adds the `concat()` functionality by having SQLite call back to PHP. For example you add it to your PhpUnit script.

The second line gets the `\PDO` handle, if you don't use Laravel, replace it with your way of getting the handle.

```php
        /** @var \Illuminate\Database\Connection $connection */
        $connection = DB::connection();
        $dbHandle = $connection->getPdo();

        // Add MySQL concat() support to SQLite
        if ('sqlite' === $dbHandle->getAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_DRIVER_NAME)) {
            $dbHandle->sqliteCreateFunction(
                'concat',
                function (...$input) {
                    return implode('', $input);
                }
            );
        }
```

Other SQLite libraries in PHP have a similar `sqliteCreateFunction()`.

- https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlite-create-function.php
- https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.sqlitecreatefunction.php
- https://www.php.net/manual/en/sqlite3.createfunction.php